# objective-c : alloc child class from parent and use parent class instance varriable

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to know if this is possible 
alloc child class from parent and use parent class instance varriable

for example, I have a parent class called PARENTCLASS and a child class CHILDCLASS. If I do something like below it doesn't work because the CHILD class is allocated and parent varrible are nil.

```
@interface PARENTCLASS : NSObject
{
    NSString *something;
}

@implementation PARENTCLASS
@synthesize something

- (void) doSomething
{
    CHILDCLASS *c = [[CHILDCLASS alloc]init];
    [c doSomething];
}
@end


and then in child subclass PARENT
@implementation PARENTCLASS
@synthesize somthing

- (void) doSomething
{
    NSLog(something);
}
@end
```

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is something like you need to initialize your `something` ivar in the parent class...but can you please be more specific about what your expected output is vs. the actual output? Also, is that second @implementation block supposed to be `@implementation CHILDCLASS`?

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual code you're using. The code you've posted won't even compile.

Comment: Each instance of ParentClass will have its own ivar 'something'. And every instance of ChildClass is also an instance of ParentClass. So your object `c` here as an ivar 'something' and the object which created it also has an ivar 'something'. So which `something` are you expecting to log? It would help to know that. (`c` also has two sets of setters/getters for `something`, but that's another issue...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, hopefully the answer is somewhere in what follows:

Instance variables defined in an `@interface` have one of the accessibilities:

- `@public` - anybody can access them
- `@private` - nobody other than the owning class can access them
- `@protected` - the owning class and any derived (child) class can access them (said the other way around a child class can access the protected instance variables of its parent, its grandparent, etc.). This is the default accessibility for `@interface` instance variables.

Instance variables defined in an `@implementation` are private to that implementation *except* that interface builder can access them.

Now the phrase "owning class" above means "*any* instance of the owning class". So for example if you have two different instances of the same class they can access each other's private instance variables. Also one of the instances can access the protected variables of the others parent. Etc. In other words, protected and private apply to the "family" of all instances of the classes and not to individual object instances.

So a simple answer to your question is: yes, a child can access its parent's public and protected instance variables.

However in your question you have a method in the parent creating a new child and then calling a method on that child and you ask can it access the parent? But which "parent" do you mean? After you have created the child there are *two* parent instances around, the original one on which the parent method was called, and the one which is part of the child object just created. Two parent objects means two sets of parent instance variables, which set are you trying to access?

The newly created child can access its parents instance variables using `self`. It has the *rights* to access the instance variables of the parent object which created it as well, but to use those rights it needs a *reference* to that creating parent. In your code example no reference to the creating parent is passed to the child so the answer is: no, your child cannot access the instance variables of its creating parent until, and if, it is passed a reference to that creator.

### Comment Followup

You could pass the *creating* instance as part of initialisation. E.g.:

```
@interface CHILDCLASS
{
    PARENTCLASS *myCreator;
}
...
@end

@implementation CHILDCLASS

- (id) initWithCreator:(PARENTCLASS *)_myCreator
{
   if((self = [super init]))
   {
      myCreator = _myCreator;
   }
   return self;
}

- (void) doSomething
{
   NSLog("My parent's something: %@", something);
   NSLog("My creator's something: %@", myCreator->something);
}
```

Is this "good practice"? There is nothing wrong *per se* with an instance having a reference to its creating instance, so its not "bad practice". However I do wonder in this case whether there is some confusion over inheritance. It is not clear why are you wishing to access the instance variables of the parent instance that created the child and not the parent instance variables which are part of the child? There is nothing *wrong* in doing this, but with current details I can't say what you're doing is "good" either.

Comment: i want the child be able to access parent variables even if the parent created the child, you said I can pass a reference to the creator(parent)? Is that a good practice?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail why you need the superclass to refer to an instance of one of its subclasses? There are few, if any, situations where this is desirable and I'm guessing this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Adam: I agree what the iosdevnyc is trying to do isn't clear here. However, surely the "class cluster" is one in which a superclass refers to instances of its subclasses, so "if any" is a wee bit too strong. What the iosdevnyc is doing isn't this though, they are trying to have a subclass access a particular instance of its superclass...